# Add few files to Stash (Git)

Tags: git, logstash, git-stash, git-apply

currently I got a few modified files into my local branch:

```
modified:   commands/abc/Test.cs
modified:   common/des/Info.cs
modified:   common/pit/Abc.cs
modified:   services/Services123.cs
```

I want to put to `stash` just first 3. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly list files to stash after `--`

`git stash -- commands/abc/Test.cs common/des/Info.cs common/pit/Abc.cs`

Then your changes in `services/Services123.cs` won't be stashed.

(Note that in your specific case you could conveniently take advantage of the file names and use a wildcard, like `git stash -- com*`)

Comment: what if I have all my files added to stage? And then I want to all files from stage put to stash?

Comment: @4est You can then use another flag, `--keep-index`, but warning : there's no `--stash-index-only` counterpart to do what you want. You'll have to 1) `git stash --keep-index` to save unstaged changes, then 2) do a regular `git stash` which will contain only your staged files, and finally recover in the working tree what you first stashed, with `git stash pop stash{1}`. At the end of this (slightly clunky) process, all your staged changes are stashed in `stash{0}`, and the other changes are in the working tree, waiting to be staged/discarded.

Comment: thx, so then I need to do:
1) git stash --keep-index 
2) git stash push -m "my_new_stash"

Comment: Yes, if you prefer to refer to your (unstaged changes) stash by a name handle rather than by its stash number like I did. Both work. (If you're unsure, try it on a test repo, it's very quick to setup with just a couple of text files.)

Comment: last qq: instead of point `2) git stash push -m "my_new_stash"`....what else I can do ?

Comment: @4est What is unclear in my first comment? I already detailed steps 2) `git stash` and 3) `git stash pop stash@{1}`. Tell me what is problematic / confusing to you. OH WOW .... Important edit : in my previous comment I made a typo that I can't correct any more now : it's not `stash{n}` but `stash@{n}` in every instance. Sorry for the added confusion.